# How to make a footer with a curved top border?

Tags: css, border, radius

I'm bad with font end design and i'm trying to make a footer with a specific shape in css. Here is the shape i want to have:

[image]

Do you know how to do it ? And if it is possible with a responsive behaviour.

I tried border-radius:
border-top-left-radius: 50% 20%;
border-top-right-radius: 50% 20%;
But the it is not what i expected.

Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: On StackOverflow, you are expected to attempt to solve the problem on your own first. Then, if you fail, try researching why and how to fix it. When all else fails, come here, present what you have tried in the form of an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), explain how it fails and what you expect instead.

Answer (score -2):

the easy way you can achieve this is to create import the curve as image an use it for footer background.

or you can use:

```
border-redius
```

Comment: Thank you i already tried border-radius and using an image seems a bit overkill. I'm really trying to do it using css

Comment: If you tried it you should mention it in your question - see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)...